# layoutSubviews() is ran every time the cell is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm developing an iOS app in Swift and I have a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCells` that have spacing at the left and right of the cell by overriding `layoutSubviews()`.

This works by subtracting 40 to `self.bounds.size.width`.

As I'm not really good at explaining, here you have an image:

[image: image of my app]

But the problem is that when I click on a cell, the overridden `layoutSubviews()` function is run again, so the cell is shrunken again as it subtracts 40 again to the **already** original `self.bounds.size.width - 40`.

[image: shrunken UITableViewCell]

How can I avoid `layoutSubviews()` running every time the cell is clicked and make it run only once when the view is load?

I do not know why the layoutSubviews is run again, as it is loaded in my custom UITableViewCell class.

Here you have my code:

```
class TBRepoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var repoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var urlLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var repoIcon: UIImageView!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // Set the width of the cell
        self.bounds = CGRect(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width - 40, self.bounds.size.height)
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}

class SourcesViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // note that indexPath.section is used rather than indexPath.row
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setEditing(false, animated: true)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TBRepoTableViewCell
        let repoArray = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.repoLabel.text = repoArray.repoName
        cell.urlLabel.text = repoArray.repoURL
        cell.repoIcon.image = repoArray.icon

        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none

        // add borders
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }
}
```

Comment: I (personally) would consider any change to the bounds a bad idea within a layout pass, but that's me.  Any reason why you can't use a auto layout constraint to inject a trailing space? Or use a transparent cell and a subview to as the primary container for the content? Then you could change the size of the custom content view based on the size of the cell?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your suggestion, I tried what you said, but when I select my `UITableViewCell`, it doesn't allow me to add trailing and leaning space. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never modify the view's frame or bounds in `layoutSubviews`. The only thing you should do there is update the frame or bounds of the view's subviews based on the current size of the view.

What you should do is modify your cell view class such that it has a view that shows the indent and the rounded corners. Let's call this a "background view". Add the other subviews of the cell to this background view. Then add the background view to the cell's contentView.

Your `cellForRowAt` should not be changing the cell's layer. That logic belongs in the custom cell class.

Comment: ok, thanks for answering. I modified the backgroundView corners, added autolayout constraints to add it spacing and made the cell background transparent, so it now makes the same effect and fixes my problem.